# Runtime error in docker container, Module not found

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I am sorry for the newbie question, but I have been figuring out this error, I have an Express app and I am trying to run it as a docker container. I've used this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine
COPY /src /nodejs
WORKDIR /nodejs
ADD package*.json ./
RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

and this is my package.js file :

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js -e js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "prom-client": "^12.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^10.4.0"
  }
}
```

I'm using windows 10 and the command I used to deploy the container is :

```
docker run --name express-api -d -p 4000:4000 docker-express-app
```

the error that I get after executing the above command, in power shell:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888

  throw err;

  ^


Error: Cannot find module '/nodejs/app.js'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)

    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)

    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

  requireStack: []

}
```

any idea on this issue is appreciated.

P.S: my project hierarchy is like so :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptlkI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't COPY the app.js file in your container.

```
WORKDIR /nodejs
COPY src .
COPY app.js .
ADD package*.json ./
RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

This should fix it.

I think a more easier way could be to make a [dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file and copy everything. Another problem is that you're using ADD instead of COPY. You just need to copy your files in the container and I think COPY would suffice as ADD [has some extra functionality](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) which can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks vanshaj, it worked for the first part but then it gives another error this time about js files under src folder(same not found modules). any idea?

Comment: Not sure. What's the path of the module in the error ?

Comment: './src/routers/router'. It is included in the app.js file.

Comment: vanshaj, I finally got it working by copying everything using COPY . .

Comment: great. make sure you don't add node_modules and other files you don't need by adding them in the dockerignore.